# SELECT * FROM col WHERE name != 'NULL' && name (is an int) - SQL PROBLEM

Tags: sql, integer

I have an sql statement which I now need to change so it only returns values back that are integers.

`SELECT * FROM col WHERE name != 'NULL'` <-- this works

But now I need to extend that to something like:

`SELECT * FROM col WHERE name != 'NULL' && name` (is an int)

But I cannot figure out the sql for this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which flavor SQL are you using?

Comment: Are you actually storing the text "NULL" in the column?  Or are you trying to eliminate NULL values from the resultset?  Your test of !='NULL' will NOT eliminate DB NULL values.

Comment: This cannot be asnswered without knowing your database backend. Even then the answer may not be simple. If you are storing both integer and character data in the same column (and want to separate them out in queries unlike part numbers which could be either but you wouldn't search for only integer parts), then they may mean differnt things and you probably do not want to store them inteh same column.

Comment: as the presence of an integer inherently means the column is not null, you don't need that check....

Answer (score 4):

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM col WHERE NOT name IS NOT NULL AND name NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM col WHERE NOT name IS NOT NULL AND ISNUMERIC(name) = 1
```

**Warning**, **ISNUMERIC** can return 1 for some non numeric characters such as +, -, or $

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) is some more information on **ISNUMERIC**

Also, when comparing against NULL in SQL you must use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: No ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type.

Comment: @Mangus I misread the part where it mentions, that monetary symbols will also produce a 1. That could be an issue though.

Comment: Tested that, but only works for `AND NOT name LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`

Answer (score 2):

For SQL server this is the Syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM col WHERE NOT name IS NULL AND ISNUMERIC(name) = 1 AND NOT name LIKE '%.%'
```

Assuming "." is used for decimals

Answer (score 0):

If you use MSSQL, 
`SELECT * FROM col WHERE name <> 'NULL' AND IsNumeric(name) = 1`

Comment: -1 for quoting the null - this returns records where the name column is not equal to the string 'null'.

Comment: yes, which is what he asked for. He says that <> 'NULL' works, which would not work if he was trying to exclude NULL values for which he would have to do a IS NOT NULL